# Make it simpler to flag duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

While browsing the `man` SO tag, I just found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195328/what-does-the-2-stand-for-in-fork2) that there are duplicates in top questions. The duplicate was found in 2011 and apparently wasn't taken care of, so I decided to report it again. I clicked "flag", then "duplicate" and was shown a list. IMHO on top of this list, there should be the duplicate that was already reported and could be found in the comments, which specifically in this case could make it simpler for me to report the issue.

Comment: It did suggest the previously identified duplicate when I went to close it.  Perhaps a difference between close-vote as duplicate (rep privilege) and flag as duplicate.  Or did you manually select it before posting here?

Answer (score 7):

The fact that the duplicate flag/vote aged out actually is a pretty strong indication that it's *not* in fact a duplicate, and that we *shouldn't* be going out of our way to lead people to using that question as a dup target.

Were the flag/vote still active and you went in to vote to close as a duplicate, that question would in fact be the top question shown.

Comment: In this case it certainly was a duplicate.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure.  I didn't say it wasn't.  I said that we shouldn't change the system to strongly encourage people to flag/vote to close as a duplicate a question that has had votes/flags to close that have since aged off.  If it really is a duplicate, then the user can vote/flag to close without being prompted to use the previous suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It's very rare for old questions to get closed as duplicate except via the gold-badge unilateral-duplicate privilege, commonly known as "the hammer" or "Mjolnir".

This is because the close vote review queue on Stack Overflow got so large that close votes and flags won't even cause a question to appear there until there are multiple which "organically" occur on the same question (meaning that multiple logged-in users had to stumble across it).  And even when the threshold for inclusion in the review queue is met, the queue is so large that many question don't get the needed attention and simply time out of the queue.

By all means, add your vote or flag when you come across an already-marked duplicate.  I was unable to reproduce your issue with the site failing to suggest the previously selected duplicate, but that might be due to your interaction with the question.

You'll have a better chance that such questions actually get closed if you bring attention to them via a chatroom (better) or meta (really only if you think there's a general principle that needs to be discussed, as here).

Comment: The OP was flagging a question that had an *already expired* flag/vote to close.  You didn't see the same thing because you were looking at a question with an *active* flag/vote to close.  Also note that the original vote to close was cast in 2010, long before there even was a close vote queue.

Comment: @Servy: My answer clearly said "that might be due to your interaction with the question"

Comment: And I was explaining, specifically, what is going on there, rather than stating that it might have to do with "some interaction", I conclusively stated what specific interaction it's dependent on.

Comment: @Servy: Except that your "conclusive" statement is just supposition.

Comment: The evidence around this behavior is pretty darn conclusive.

Comment: [I have flagged, but my flag was denied](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262159/years-old-clearly-duplicate-questions-not-closed-weeks-after-voting-to-close).

Comment: @Dan you have the vote to close privilege. Flag is for users without that privilege. Try the chat rooms when there aren't enough votes.